# NextJS i18n match locale with pages subdirectory

Tags: internationalization, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

### Background

When using i18n in NextJS, locales are detected automagically, but routes are matched without the locale.

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'nl', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    // localeDetection: false
  }
}
```

I want to have a structure in pages that allows me to place the translated files in a way that the locale is matched

Folder structure:

```
pages
├── es
│   ├── gsp
│   │   ├── [slug].js
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── gssp.js
├── gsp
│   ├── [slug].js
│   └── index.js
├── gssp.js
└── index.js
```

The above example is taken from [i18n-routing example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/i18n-routing) which you can reproduce easily with `yarn create next-app --example i18n-routing i18n-app`

### Problem

I want to have this file structure because I will be using mdx/md files and translations will be in full so i18n translations with single files such as [sulg].js which detect locale through `useRouter()` do not work for the problem I want to solve.

### Question

How can I setup the server so that **locale** in routes like

- `/some-random-route` (which would be default 'en') or
- `/es/some-random-route` (which would be explicitly set to 'es')

are matched to serve the files in the pages subdirectories?

Comment: Hey, have you ever managed to solve your problem?